# Help understanding vector-by-vector differentiation identity

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

So I have very recently been introduced to matrix caluclus, and I have read and been following the quite nice Wikipedia article on the topic ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector_identities)). However, I do have a bit of trouble understanding this vector by vector identity.
$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{I}$$
where $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the identity matrix.
So, here is my question where does this identity come from and how is it derived? From my point of view I don't get why a vector suddenly can become a matrix.
Any help on how to derive this identity will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look higher up in the article where they _define_ vector-by-vector differentiation ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector))?This identity is just a particular (and honestly rather straight-forward) special case. Maybe instead you actually want to ask how vector-by-vector differentiation works in general?

Comment: Okay, so just to check if I understand it correctly. The reason why it equals the identity is that the derivative only equals 1 in the diagonal where the i'th row equals the j'th column and otherwise zero?

Comment: Yep. Changing the $i$th coordinate changes the $j$th coordinate according to the identity matrix.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. I Think I got it now. Sometimes it makes you see things from another perspective when formulating a question I guess. Once again thanks a lot.